# Gulp: What's the easiest way to take in XML files, count how many of a certain element there are, and write the output to another XML?

Tags: xml-parsing, gulp

Let's say I have many XML files with similar structures, for example

```
<root id="xmlFile1">
  <subroot id="sr1">
    <node att="abc">Some text here 1</node>
  </subroot>
  <subroot id="sr2">
    <node att="def">Some text here 2</node>
    <node att="abc">Some text here 3</node>
  </subroot>
</root>
```

I want to count how many `<node>` values there are in each XML, and output the result to another XML using Gulp. The final XML could look something like:

```
<totals>
  <file>
    <name>xmlFile1</file>
    <numNodes>3</numNodes>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>xmlFile2</file>
    <numNodes>26</numNodes>
  </file>
</totals>
```

So basically, I'm looking for some function where I could do

```
gulp.task('countNodes', function ()
{
  gulp.src('./app/**/my.xml').pipe(...).dest('./app/totals.xml');
});
```

What's the easiest way to fill in the `...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a xml parsing library like [gulp-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-xml). You can use the callback function to then run any regex parsing and either write out your XML manually or use [gulp-xml-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-xml-editor) to format the output for you.

Comment: Does it matter that the output xml is completely different from the input xmls? I basically just want to construct one xml with the node totals results from the inputs.

Comment: You will have to construct the XML output yourself, so it can be anything you want with any values that you got from parsing the source XML.